# Python - format dataframe index

Tags: python, dataframe, formatting

My original df.index is in yyyy-mm-dd format (not a datetime dtype, it is a str). How to I format it as ddmmmyyyy?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=['2017-01-01', '2017-02-01', '2017-03-01'], 
          columns=["A", "B", "C"], 
          data=[[5,np.nan, "ok"], [7,8,"fine"], ["3rd",100,np.nan]])
df1
```

[image]

The result that I need:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to programmatically change it? Otherwise you can just change the string literal lie 3.6 biturbo suggested: 
`df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=['01JAN2017', '01FEB2017', '01MAR2017'], 
          columns=["A", "B", "C"], 
          data=[[5,np.nan, "ok"], [7,8,"fine"], ["3rd",100,np.nan]])
    df1`

Otherwise you could try:

`df['date'] = df['datetime'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%d%m%Y'))
     df['time'] = df['datetime'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%H%M%S'))`

Answer (score 1):

use [DatetimeIndex.strftime()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html) method

```
In [193]: df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1.index).strftime('%d%b%Y')

In [194]: df1
Out[194]:
             A      B     C
01Jan2017    5    NaN    ok
01Feb2017    7    8.0  fine
01Mar2017  3rd  100.0   NaN
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this solution

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=['01JAN2017', '01FEB2017', '01MAR2017'], 
          columns=["A", "B", "C"], 
          data=[[5,np.nan, "ok"], [7,8,"fine"], ["3rd",100,np.nan]])
df1
```